# Wrapping paragraphs/new line in p tags

Tags: regex

I have multiple text file and need to wrap each paragraph in p tags using regex.

i.e. before:

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

After

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

I tried different regexs from other questions but with no luck. The closest i got was to use find `(.*?(\n))` and replace with `<p>$1</p>` but the output looks like this:

```
<p>parag1
</p><p>
</p><p>parag2
</p><p>
</p><p>parag3
</p><p>
</p><p>parag4
```

Any idea how can i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(.+?)(\n|$)+
```

and replace it with:

```
<p>$1</p>\n\n
```

The problem with your regex is, that it is matching empty lines as well, because you're saying: "Match any character *zero* or more times, followed by a new line".

You also have to take in count the last paragraph, that might not end with a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\w+\s+\d+)
```

Then replace with

```
<p>$1</p>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4kG2/1)

Comment: Your regex seems to have been tailored to the sample text: `Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph 2\n\nParagraph 3`.  I think `(.+)` will do fine.